# How can I transfer a file with special character to my Android SDcard?

Tags: android, filesystems, sd-card, file-copying

Recently I'm in trouble about creating file in Android SD card with special character from iPhone.

My device : Galaxy Note4 KitKat. 
My PC : Window7

I got a file from iPhone to my PC. 
This file contains an emoticon (http://chars.suikawiki.org/string?s=%F0%9F%90%8D) 
I could transfer this file to internal SDcard from my PC but I could not transfer to removable SDcard.

Even I can't transfer copied file from internal to removable, too.( I used FileOutputStream, File.createNewFile to copy)

I suspected SDcard's file system and tried to other FAT16(2GB sandisk Sdcard ), exFAT(64GB samsung SDcard).

But I failed both.

I tried to found file system spec but i found nothing related. 
I also suspected reserved file title characters, but it was not related.

In short,

1. Why cannot transfer this file to removable SDcard?
2. How to copy programmatically this file to SDcard without renaming ?

===== add snippet =====

Below special character seems emoticon in Android device file browser but in my PC, it looks ordinal special character.

new File("/storage/emulated/0/.txt").createNewFile(); //internal storage. work.

new File("/storage/extSdCard/.txt").createNewFile();//removable storage. not work

Comment: Your story does not make sense. The contents of a file can never be the reason that it cannot be copied. A file is just a sequence of bytes.Show your copy code please.

Comment: `This file contains an emoticon (http://chars.suikawiki.org/string?s=%F0%9F%90%8D) `. That is not a file. That is an url which delivers a html page. Please elaborate. What are you doing with that page?

Comment: Hi @greenapps . I know it seems nonsense. But it is real. That file name is displaying in my PC "". But in my Android phone, that file name seems combination of the emoticon which I mentioned. 
You can test my code below. 
new File("/storage/emulated/0/.txt").createNewFile(); //internal storage. work.
new File("/storage/extSdCard/.txt").createNewFile();//removable storage. not work

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Please change the subject of your post. You are suggesting that a file cannot contain special characters. But now we see that you mean a file name. That is another story. You have omitted a lot of info for us. You did not tell what the file name was. You did not tell what a file name had to do with the url you posted. Removable storage is mostly FAT and maybe uses a different charset. Maybe you have to use a different one first.

Comment: @greenapps I found this is because of file system difference. Android internal storage file system is FUSE. but external is FAT. I need to study more about this. Thanks greenapps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled onto a similar issue with saving to SD. It appears to be a security issue. You now need to use the Storage Access Framework [See Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html).

You could use the files allocated to your Application though and not have to use the Storage Access Framework. One way to access your Applications data directory is by either using:

```
ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, type)
```

Which would be backwards compatible. Or you could use the following for Lollipop Users

```
Context.getExternalMediaDirs()
```

Each of this method will give you 2 Directories. 1 for internal memory and other for SD (If device has slot). From here you can save all your application specific data.

BE WARNED: this data will be deleted if user ever uninstalls your application.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is related file name contains special character. I tried to make "aaa.txt" in path which i got from getExternalFilesDirs. I succeed. But I failed with ".txt". I'll change my question again.

Comment: 'Hope this helped'. Your answer does not solve the problem. Why it is marked as correct is a mystery to me as it is completely out of context.